# User Inputs and Conditional statements along with Code Executional delay and Loops

Tags: python-3.x

This is my Mad Libs Project. I am a beginner so I tried to mixed all my learnings in Python which are User Inputs, Variables, Conditional Statements, and etc. Unfornately, It doesnt work and I cant identify the problem. For me its all good, I guess. I hope you could help me guys.

Please bear with me. I am still a noob.

```
import time

name = input('Hello! What is your name? ')
print('Hi! ' + name + ' I\'m Sean. Nice to meet you!')
time.sleep(2)

def main():
    ans = input('\'Wanna play a game? ').upper()
    
    if ans='YES':
        print('Great! Lets get started')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('The called Mad Libs. \nThe mechanics is simple, your going to give words according to its category \nand your answer will be added to my script I made beforehand.')
        def main2()
        ans2=input('Are you ready? ').lower()
        
        if ans2=='yes':
            Vegetable = input('Vegetable: ')
            Superhero = input('Superhero: ')
            Celebrity = input('Celebrity: ')
            Country = input('Country: ')
            Time_of_day = input(r'Time of day (ex. 11:11): ')
            Number = input('Number: ')
            Vegetable2 = input('Another Vegetable: ')
            Childhood_toy = input('Childhood Toy: ')
            Liquid = input(r'Liquid (ex. water,ketchup,etc.): ')
            Joke = input('Joke Quote: ')
            Emotion = input('Emotion: ')
            Unusual_pet = input('A unusual pet: ')
            Plant = input('A plant: ')
            Body_part = input('A body part: ')
            Furniture = input('Furniture: ')
            Number2 = input('Another number: ')
            Animal = input('Another animal: ')
            Food = input('Food: ')
            Catchphrase = input('A Catchphrase: ')
        
        elif ans2=='no':
            print('Aww! Maybe next time.')
            
        else:
            print('I didn\'t quite understand that, come again?').lower()
            main2()

    elif ans=='NO':
        print('Aww! Maybe next time.')
        time.sleep(3)
        exit()

    else:
        print('I didn\'t quite understand that, come again?').lower()
        main()

main()
```

Comment: What specifically doesn't work about it, and what behavior are you expecting?

Comment: `if ans='YES':` needs to be `if ans=='YES':` though. And `def main2()` floating there will causes errors as well.

Comment: shall i remove def main2() ?

Comment: It depends on what your intent is. Are you trying to create a function `main2` *inside* of `main`? If you're trying to use recursion to ask the user for input, wrapping the code you want to repeat in a `while` loop would be cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

name = input('Hello! What is your name? ')
print('Hi! ' + name + ' I\'m Sean. Nice to meet you!')
time.sleep(2)


def main():
    ans = input('\'Wanna play a game? ').upper()

    if ans == 'YES':  # Was missing an equal sign
        print('Great! Lets get started')
        time.sleep(2)
        print(
            'The called Mad Libs. \nThe mechanics is simple, your going to give words 
        according to its category \nand your answer will be added to my script I made 
        beforehand.')

        def main2():  # Was missing colon
            ans2 = input('Are you ready? ').lower()
            # Everything below was not indented
            if ans2 == 'yes':
                Vegetable = input('Vegetable: ')
                Superhero = input('Superhero: ')
                Celebrity = input('Celebrity: ')
                Country = input('Country: ')
                Time_of_day = input(r'Time of day (ex. 11:11): ')
                Number = input('Number: ')
                Vegetable2 = input('Another Vegetable: ')
                Childhood_toy = input('Childhood Toy: ')
                Liquid = input(r'Liquid (ex. water,ketchup,etc.): ')
                Joke = input('Joke Quote: ')
                Emotion = input('Emotion: ')
                Unusual_pet = input('A unusual pet: ')
                Plant = input('A plant: ')
                Body_part = input('A body part: ')
                Furniture = input('Furniture: ')
                Number2 = input('Another number: ')
                Animal = input('Another animal: ')
                Food = input('Food: ')
                Catchphrase = input('A Catchphrase: ')

            elif ans2 == 'no':
                print('Aww! Maybe next time.')

            else:
                print('I didn\'t quite understand that, come again?')  # There should be no .lower() on a print function
                main2()
            # Everything above was not indented

        main2()  # You only defined main2(), you never actually used it
    elif ans == 'NO':
        print('Aww! Maybe next time.')
        time.sleep(3)
        exit()

    else:
        print('I didn\'t quite understand that, come again?')  # There should be no .lower() on a print function
        main()


main()
```